# EditText.getText().toString() error

Tags: android, android-edittext

there is this code I'm working with, and the log shows that there is an error that terminates the app like

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.amuna.project1.addWord.confirmBtnClicked(addWord.java:25)
```

and the code is

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class addWord extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText wordEdit, defEdit;
Button confirmButton;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    wordEdit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.wordAdd);
    defEdit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.defAdd);
    confirmButton=findViewById(R.id.confirmBtn);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_word);
}
public void confirmBtnClicked(View v){
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    String newWord = wordEdit.getText().toString();
    String newDef = defEdit.getText().toString();
    editor.putString("word", newWord);
    editor.putString("def", newDef);
    editor.commit();

}
}
```

please help! It's String newWord = wordEdit.getText().toString(); that has an error, and please notice me if I have anything more wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Did you debug and verify that `wordEdit` in fact is being initialized to a non null reference?

Comment: you need to bind your views after setContentView(..)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set the content view, by calling `setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_word);`, before `wordEdit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.wordAdd);`.  Change the code as follows:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_word);
    wordEdit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.wordAdd);
    defEdit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.defAdd);
    confirmButton=findViewById(R.id.confirmBtn);

}
```

Comment: Okay, I'll try that!

Comment: Thanks! I think it worked! The app doesn't quit any more!

Comment: @이정민 great! Remember to mark answer as accepted so that others can benefit too

Comment: And one more thing, remember to call `super` just after the method name.

Comment: Ok, I just marked your answer and Thank you again! It works very well!

Comment: @Sagar great answer!!
but you should tell why we set setContentview first the set other elements.

Comment: @Arbaz.in its because `findViewById` looks through view hierarchy and returns reference to a view with requested viewId. `setContentView` will set the activity content from a layout resource by inflating the resource, due to which the view will be available to hierarchy and consequently can be detected by `findViewById`

Comment: @Sagar great i really appreciate for your valuable/informative response.

Comment: @Arbaz.in no problem. Remember to cast your vote in case the answer was useful. Enjoy coding :-)

Comment: @Sagar yeah sure